# How do you generally tell the independence of events in a probability problem when it is not outright stated?

Tags: probability

First question, do probability problems generally consisting of two categories always assume two events are dependent?

Let's say there are two categories from a set of n people. They are gender, divided into $M$ - male and $F$ - female and course which are $E$ - engineer and $D$ - doctor.

I will assign variables for each of the four unions.
$$M ∩ E = a$$
$$F ∩ E = b$$
$$M ∩ D = c$$
$$M ∩ D = d$$

My question is, why is that with these kinds of problems we always go for conditional probability? Is it because they have intersection as given? From my conceptual understanding of dependent events, I don't think gender and preferred course are suppose to intuitively be related.

Okay someone might argue they could be. But why is it if like the problem involves x category and y category and they just give out values we just always go for the idea that they are dependent?

The bigger question is, how do you if a problem uses dependent or independent events without just relying on common types of problems?

Is it right like that if two things can happen at the same time for like a person or product, we just go for it being dependent? But if two things can happen at the same time but they do not pertain to the same subject, they are independent? Like the event that it rains in City A and it is sunny in City B is independent because they can totally happen at the same time but they don't really talk about the same thing?

The independence of events depending on their subject was just an assumption of mine. Is this true or not? Is there any generalization on how to tell the independence of two events in the problem when it is not outright stated like in the one I mentioned above?

Comment: If you have no a priori information, then you should assume dependence. Then the data might persuade you that independence is plausible.  Or you might have some understanding of the situation which leads you to assume independence in advance...but as a practical matter, I'd be careful with that.

Comment: Probability and statistics is often counter-intuitive. That's the reasons studying these problems is so useful. Simpson's paradox and the Monty Hall Problem are famous examples but there are many others.

Comment: Gender and course probably are related: most people would guess that a higher proportion of engineering students are male than the proportion of medical students.  Weather in different cities are likely to be related, when it is cold in New York City, it is probably cold in Newark, New Jersey nearby but more likely to be warm in Sydney, Australia (as winter in the northern hemisphere coincides with summer in the south).  On the other hand, it you flip a coin twice, the results might be assumed to be independent given the coin, because it does not remember what happened on the previous flip.

Comment: Henry's comment captures my idea. Like, so isn't there a generalization that can be made with independent and dependent events based on what you said citing the gender and course situation against the coin flip one rather than having to rely on intuition that the events are independent or not?

Comment: You should rely on neither intuition nor generalizations!  When in doubt, assume dependence.  That, of course, does not preclude independence and the data will help you proceed.  In the end, the data matters much more than any preconceived notion.

Comment: You need to proofread better.  You called them unions, but they are intersections.  More important equation for d is wrong.